# How to get correct value when calculate sum with columns in when case on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm using and facing the problem when i get data ouput with wrong value when use CASE WHEN to calculate sum of columns. I use CTE in Oracle

this is LOG0104M table with datas following as:

```
  PRODUCT_NAME      TOTAL_QUANTITY  PACKING_STYLE   QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN
  ---------------   --------------  -------------   ---------------------
  FILTER-DOUBLE           17              30                 1
  FILTER-14INCH           28              30                 1
  FILTER-PLUS 11INCH(S)   56              30                 1
  FILTER-14INCH           22              30                 1
```

this is my query:

```
WITH BOXCOUNT AS (
SELECT  LM.PRODUCT_CODE ,
        LM.QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN ,
        ROUND(SUM(LM.TOTAL_QUANTITY / LM.PACKING_STYLE)) AS FULLBOX,
        CASE WHEN ROUND(SUM(TOTAL_QUANTITY - QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN)) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS SPAREBOX 
FROM 
    LOG0104M LM
GROUP BY 
    PRODUCT_CODE,
    QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN
 )

SELECT  
  LO04.PRODUCT_NAME,
  LO04.TOTAL_QUANTITY,
  LO04.PACKING_STYLE,
  LO04.QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN,
  BC.FULLBOX,
  BC.SPAREBOX,
  ROUND(SUM(LO04.TOTAL_QUANTITY - BC.FULLBOX * LO04.PACKING_STYLE)) AS SPARE_QUANTITY,
  SUM(BC.FULLBOX + BC.SPAREBOX) TOTALBOX
  FROM LOG0104M LO04
  JOIN BOXCOUNT BC
  ON BC.PRODUCT_CODE = LO04.PRODUCT_CODE 
  GROUP BY
    LO04.PRODUCT_NAME ,
    LO04.QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN,
    LO04.TOTAL_QUANTITY ,
    LO04.PACKING_STYLE,
    BC.FULLBOX,
    BC.SPAREBOX
```

Logic and my reciepe:

```
  1. Full box = total qty / packing style

  2. Spare box: base one spare qty
     Spare qty = total qty - full box * packing style.
          If spare qty = 0 => spare box = 0
          If spare qty > 0 => spare box = 1.0   

   3. total box = full box + spare box
```

when I run my query, it output wrong result following as:

```
PRODUCT_NAME TOTAL_QUANTITY PACKING_STYLE QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN  FULLBOX SPAREBOX SPARE_QUANTITY    TOTALBOX
----------   ------------   -----------     ----------------    -----   -------- -------------      -------
 FILTER-DOUBLE 17             30             1                   1       1             -13              2
 FILTER-14INCH 28             30             1                   3       1             -62              4
 FILTER-PLUS   56             30             1                   3       1             -34              4
 FILTER-14INCH 22             30             1                   1       1              -8              2
```

this is expected result, and to be correct result:

```
  PRODUCT_NAME TOTAL_QUANTITY PACKING_STYLE  QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN  FULLBOX  SPAREBOX SPARE_QUANTITY TOTALBOX
  -----------  ------------   ------------   ------------------  ------   ------  ------------      -------
  FILTER-DOUBLE 17            30                   1              1         1         480              2
  FILTER-14INCH 28            30                   1              1         1         810              2
  FILTER-PLUS    56           30                   1              2         1         1.620            3
  FILTER-14INCH  22           30                   1              1         1         630              2
```

How  to fix the problem ? many thank

Comment: Please explain the logic for the columns you are calculating.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I have updated with my reciepe and logic

Comment: How do you expect to have 2 total boxes for qty = 17 and packing_style = 30? Also your formulas have no roundings, so `spare_qty` should always be zero for them: `total_qty - fullbox*packing_style = total_qty - (total_qty / packing_style) * packing_style = total_qty - total_qty = 0`

Comment: I am executing same code with same data and the output of result is different.
Additionally you are using something like PRODUCT_CODE? or PRODUCT_NAME? how your code works?

Comment: Also I no understand this ROUND function if has any sense, I think you need to put it into nested query.

Comment: Hi @astentx: i got it, could you answer for me

Comment: Hi @VahramDanielyan: I'm using PRODUCT_CODE, Could you answer for me as text and i can copy/paste

Comment: I cannot help you because I have no idea why do you expect 2 boxes for 17 items when single box capacity is 30 (if I correctly understand you semantics).

Comment: @astentx: yes i see, but my value is only temp value, we can set new value to fix the problem

Comment: Maybe i will create with another question to easier understand